# Rollback everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, heroku, rollback

I will be making changes to a production app soon and I would like to know how to rollback all changes to the database and code. I think with pgbackups and if needed heroku db:push and pull that will rollback the database, but what about the code? Is there a way using git that this could be done, or maybe just to copy the whole folder and copy it back in if there are errors and upload everything again?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For managing your code, use [git tags](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

1. Find the commit of the code currently in production and tag it.
2. Add a new tag to the HEAD commit you intend to push to production

If the code needs to be rolled back, you can target the older tag during your push to heroku.

You can run `git log` to see the history of commits. Find the commit made just prior to your last push to production. Find the hash for that commit *(on the same line as the git message in the log)* and tag it

```
git tag -a v0.1 THEHASH
```

Now tag your `HEAD`

```
git tag -a v0.2
```

Now push to heroku

```
git push -f heroku v0.2^{}:master
```

If things go bad, rollback to `v.0.1`

```
git push -f heroku v0.1^{}:master
```

Comment: Ok, I'm new to git so can you show the commands for checking out the tagged git and commit it as the new head, and then push to heroku?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the pure git workflow, however heroku does support releases.

`heroku releases` will list all your releases. `heroku releases:rollback v1` will create a new release containing exactly your slug as of the v1 release.

Neither this nor the git based rollback would make any changes to your data, so if there were data migrations run they'd have to be manually rolled back as well.